# jQuery animate height of div to how much text is in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have built a simple animate feature where you click an expanding box, i would prefer not to use a plugin if possible.

At the moment it looks like this:

```
$('#one').css("height", "22");
    $('#t1').click(function() {
      if ($('#one').hasClass("extended")) {
        $('#one').stop(true, true).animate({height: '22px'},500);
        $('#one').removeClass("extended");
        $('#a1').stop(true, true).animate({opacity: '1'},500);
      } else {
        $('#one').animate({height: '120px'},500);
        $('#one').addClass("extended");
        $('#a1').animate({opacity: '0'},300);
      }
});
```

But the problem is, if the text inside the div overflows then how can i set it to be the height of the text? I hope this made sense!

The HTML:

```
<div class="rightBox">
    <div id="one" style="overflow:hidden;">
        <h3><a href="#" id="t1">Availability</a></h3><p id="a1"><a href="#" title="Slide Down"><img src="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/img/arrow.png" alt="Arrow" /></a></p>
        <?php include 'availability.php'; ?>
    </div>
</div><!-- END.#rightBox -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way that I approached this is to calculate the height of all of the children and then start the animate to that particular height. See below.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheJoeFletch/235pC/).

```
<div class="rightBox">
    <div id="one" style="overflow:hidden;">
        <h3><a href="#" id="t1">Availability</a></h3><p id="a1"><a href="#" title="Slide Down"><img src="/img/arrow.png" alt="Arrow" /></a></p>
        <p>Sample text</p>        
                <p>Sample text</p>        
                <p>Sample text</p>        
                <p>Sample text</p>        
                <p>Sample text</p>        
                <span>More Sample text</span>        
    </div> </div>​
```

jQuery/javascript

```
$('#one').css({"height": "22px", "background-color": "red"});

    $('#t1').click(function() {

      if ($('#one').hasClass("extended")) {
        $('#one').stop(true, true).animate({height: '22px'},500);
        $('#one').removeClass("extended");
        $('#a1').stop(true, true).animate({opacity: '1'},500);
      } else {
        var height = 0;//initialize a height
        $(this).closest("div").children().each(function(){//this loops through each child element
           height += $(this).outerHeight(true);//this sums up the height
        });
        $('#one').animate({height: height + 'px'},500);//set the height
        $('#one').addClass("extended");
        $('#a1').animate({opacity: '0'},300);
      } });​
```

Comment: Wow thank you! This is brilliant, I will take a look through the documentation for what you have just provided! It seems I have much much to learn! I will accept the answer when it allows me and given an up vote :)

Comment: Upvote because this solution was going to be part two of my answer but I noticed you beat me to it by a couple minutes. Jerk. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the HTML, you can wrap the contents of `#one` with another `<div>` and dynamically grab the height of that.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/88u76/

I'm also showing in that example some chaining that you can do with your code so you don't have to continually call `$( '#one' )` which causes a DOM lookup each time. Better than that even would be to set that to a variable that you could just reuse:

```
var $one = $( '#one' );
```

Comment: Good call on the caching of the `$('#one')` element!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put the text in a wrapper? either a p or a div, and do a .slideToggle() on it?
Eliminate all of the unnecessary calculation?

```
<div class="rightBox">
    <div id="one" style="overflow:hidden;">
        <h3><a href="#" id="t1">Availability</a></h3><p id="a1"><a href="#" title="Slide Down"> .. </a></p>
        <p class="content" style="display:none">afasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
        as
        df
        asd <br />
        f
        asd
        f
        asd <br />
        f
        asd
        f
        asdf <br />
            afasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
        as
        df
        asd <br />
        f
        asd
        f
        asd <br />
        f
        asd
        f
        asdf <br />
            afasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
        as
        df
        asd <br />
        f
        asd
        f
        asd <br />
        f
        asd
        f
        asdf <br />
            afasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
        as
        df
        asd <br />
        f
        asd
        f
        asd <br />
        f
        asd
        f
        asdf <br />
            afasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
        as
        df
        asd <br />
        f
        asd
        f
        asd <br />
        f
        asd
        f
        asdf <br />
        </p>
    </div>
</div><!-- END.#rightBox -->​
```

Javascript:

```
$('#t1').click(function() {
          if ($('#one').hasClass("extended")) {
            $('#one p.content').slideToggle();
              //$('#one').stop(true, true).animate({height: '22px'},500);
            $('#one').removeClass("extended");
            $('#a1').stop(true, true).animate({opacity: '1'},500);
          } else {
            //$('#one').animate({height: 'auto'},500);
            $('#one p.content').slideToggle();
              $('#one').addClass("extended");
            $('#a1').animate({opacity: '0'},300);
          }
    });​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NxwL8/